# How to stream Large size videos from google drive in vlc

Tags: google-drive-api, vlc

I've uploaded a large size video that is almost 2gb to my google drive. I'm streaming it in vlc media player. my format for upload is https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1wLllY5K1D6tdakUqHSQBqSQpFw4KclZ1 
I'm getting through shareable link. This is small size video and it's streaming but When I upload a large size video it's not able to play.

I've changed the folder permissions to public

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not related to programming.

Answer (score 0):

Due to the file-size, Google cannot automatically scan for viruses.

Thanks to this, the link you are using will show a page like this:

[image: Virus warning]

Even if you then add the parameters from the url of the "Download Anyways" button, you would not be able to proceed since the parameters are validated against Google servers to verify that the authorization was indeed done by the user at the time of asking.

Drive is not meant for video streaming, there are other solutions for it, like Youtube.

Comment: my file is public, then why it still needs authorization

Comment: @Muhammad there is no issue related to authorization. The problem is that this file is too large so Google won't allow you to download without accepting a prompt for it. Please upload your videos to YouTube if you have the need to watch such large files.